# How to add specific boost library to MINGW include path

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I am trying to set up the boost libraries for C++ in Visual Studio Code: I have extracted the zip file to my program files but when I go to build it all with `bootstrap.bat` it comes up with this error. It works fine for the first 4 then stops. I have no additional permissions set up

```
C:\Users\*user*>cd "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0"

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0>bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local
Found with vswhere C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
Found with vswhere C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
Call_If_Exists "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"  AMD64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.0.5
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
###
### Using 'vc143' toolset.
###

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine>"cl" /nologo /MP /MT /TP /Feb2 /wd4996 /O2 /GL /EHsc   -DNDEBUG  builtins.cpp class.cpp command.cpp compile.cpp constants.cpp cwd.cpp debug.cpp debugger.cpp execcmd.cpp execnt.cpp execunix.cpp filent.cpp filesys.cpp fileunix.cpp frames.cpp function.cpp glob.cpp hash.cpp hcache.cpp hdrmacro.cpp headers.cpp jam.cpp jamgram.cpp lists.cpp make.cpp make1.cpp md5.cpp mem.cpp modules.cpp native.cpp object.cpp option.cpp output.cpp parse.cpp pathnt.cpp pathsys.cpp pathunix.cpp regexp.cpp rules.cpp scan.cpp search.cpp jam_strings.cpp startup.cpp subst.cpp sysinfo.cpp timestamp.cpp variable.cpp w32_getreg.cpp modules/order.cpp modules/path.cpp modules/property-set.cpp modules/regex.cpp modules/sequence.cpp modules/set.cpp /link kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib
builtins.cpp
class.cpp
command.cpp
compile.cpp
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\class.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\class.obj': Permission denied
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\command.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\command.obj': Permission denied
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\compile.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\compile.obj': Permission denied
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\builtins.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine\builtins.obj': Permission denied
cl : Command line error D8040 : error creating or communicating with child process

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine>dir *.exe
 vol drive c
 vol serial number

 Directory of C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine

File Not Found

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0\tools\build\src\engine>copy /b .\b2.exe .\bjam.exe
The system cannot find the file specified.

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_78_0>
```

All I want these for is for the Python Library, is there a way to move said library directly into the MINGW include file and ignore the rest that won't work?

Comment: My advice is not to try to build inside of Program Files. Put the source code in a folder that is not protected by UAC (which prevents writing unless your process is elevated) and does not have spaces in the path.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm